Изменение никнейма дискорд бота на сервере через код Python
Код на питоне. Возникла потребность изменять никнейм бота прямо на сервере через его код так, чтобы этим могли пользоваться все те, у кого есть нужные права на сервере и не нужно было бы вручную менять через сайт дискорда developers. Во время выполнения какой нибудь из других команд, или создать отдельную. Есть ли такая возможность? С ролями проблем никаких нет. Нужен только код для изменения ника бота.

А код-то сам где?
